# Can you disable a custom mapping strategy?

Tags: java, mapstruct, spi

From what I can tell, when you declare a SPI, then the mapstruct build process simply chooses it over the default implementation and that's that. I see no way of saying

```java
@EnumMappingStratecy(class = DefaultMappingStrategy.class)
Target myMapping(Source s);
```

Or anything similar. Am I wrong?

Context, we are using https://github.com/entur/mapstruct-spi-protobuf and had no idea how bad it was when doing enums that don't 100% adhere to the google way of over-naming members. And just breaks and we'd rather not use it.

BUT, I just can't find anything on how I could disable this strategy, while keeping the rest. The author didn't include a mechanism. But I think mapstruct should have a way of overriding even if the author didn't provide any.

Comment: see https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#custom-enum-naming-strategy